Why are non-funded Master's degrees and their recipients frowned upon even though this is true for the majority of them?
I'm a fourth year Ph.D student who (fingers crossed) is slated to graduate this summer with their Ph.D in Experimental Psychology. Prior to this program, I did my Master's in Experimental Psychology at an institution that Carnegie Classifications lists as an M1. My Master's was accepted in full for this Ph.D program.
There is something I've wondered though. Why are non funded MA/MS degrees frowned upon? Same also goes those who received them too.
I ask this since, although I got a Research Assistantship for 10 hours both years I was in my Master's program, tuition wasn't waived at all (although I got a stipend to live). The program overall (I got in-state tuition my second year) set me back (roughly) $25k total and have $52k in student loan debt (including interest). I am kicking myself for it a bit since I passed on a fully funded offer for a general Psychology degree that was this (admittedly weird) mix of clinical and experimental courses (the Psychology department at this school in Louisiana had a separate Experimental and Clinical program at one point, but it merged. I'm guessing this was due to budget restrictions perhaps?). 90% of students for that fully funded program who were interested in Ph.D programs got offers of admission to Ph.D programs (that data was published years after I finished my Master's), whereas that number was 80% for the program I chose (in addition to actually being specialized).
I feel stupid for my decision in a lot of ways, but I do admit that program was the only one that let me do a thesis on what I wanted to do (neurodivergent traits) and didn't let me compromise or "meet halfway" on what I wanted to do research wise for a Ph.D program (and this helped me get admitted to where I am doing my Ph.D now). I would change things if I could go back in time, but it got me to where I needed to be at the same time. So, why is this still frowned upon? I've also seen some folks take it a step further and frown upon folks who are just unfunded entirely in general, which I find kind of unfair. Another example is that the students in the standalone MS program (also Experimental Psychology) where I am doing my Ph.D are totally unfunded in this case. Definitely curious why this is the case for sure.

Who frowns on them other than those who need to pay?

What country are we talking about?

@MaartenBuis US in this case.

I don't think anyone seriously frowns upon non-funded master's degrees - at least in general/in the real world. Many master's degrees are not funded. In fact, I would say that in most fields, funded master's are the exception. On top of that, no one will ever ask if you paid for your degree. But you can always count on students to fixate and form judgements on weird and arbitrary things. Most people outgrow that eventually.
That being said, obviously you are encountering this opinion. As for why, I can only speculate. My best guess is that funded programs (at any level) are generally more competitive and perhaps there is an idea that an unfunded master's program will take "anyone with a pulse and a checkbook". I've seen this before, and it can leave a bad taste in the mouth of funded/PhD students and professors who might have to deal with less than stellar unfunded students. This same thinking can occur at the department level - universities are ultimately businesses and students = tuition dollars. So departments might, against their will, be forced to offer more, larger classes and advise more students. And, like I already said, there is an argument that unfunded master's programs may be less selective (keep in mind that this is incredibly institution dependant) and so admit weaker/less motivated students who might be a hassle to deal with.
It could also be tied to the (again possibly imaginary) stigma against unfunded PhDs. Often paying goes hand-in-hand with questionable online degrees. This is still an unfair generalization though. There are plenty of doctoral level degrees that are not traditionally funded yet are high quality and otherwise legit.
Then there is the age-old elitism common in academia. Some people will find any small factor to put others down - not getting a funded position is low hanging fruit for those inclined to turn their nose up at others. Plus, I'm sure we've all encountered that one professor who hates teaching undergrad classes because it is "beneath" him/her. We could conceivably extend that attitude to unfunded master's students as well.
I want to be clear that the reasons I gave are not really "legit" or all that justifiable. I'm just offering possibilities based on what I have personally experienced. I would not worry about it.
And really, if you are happy with where you are, then why spend time worrying about what others might think? I sounds like you had good reasons to choose the program you did. Funded or not, it seems to have worked out for you.
